# Pixel spacing between percentage width divs (in columns)?

Tags: css, html, width, percentage

I've searched all over this website and found many similar issues, but couldn't find a fix that worked for my situation.

So, I wanted to test a new layout that would show two columns, and in each column a box can be added with some text.

My problem is that I want an absolute amount of space between the columns (e.g. 5px).

I tried to achieve this by setting each column's width to ~49%, but this will actually overlap the columns at a certain point if the window is re-sized too small.

I also would like to keep a margin of 5px from the left and right side of the screen.

Here's a JSFiddle of what I've tried:
http://jsfiddle.net/sbz3k/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="logo">logo here</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <!--left side-->
        <div class="box">test
            <br/>test
            <br/>test</div>
        <!--left side end-->
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <!--right side-->
        <div class="box">test
            <br/>test
            <br/>test
            <br/>test
            <br/>test
            <br/>test
            <br/>test</div>
        <!--right side end-->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

relevant CSS:

```
.wrapper {
position:relative;
padding-top:88px;
width:100%;
}

.left {
padding:3px;
width:49%;
left:5px;
position:absolute;
}

.right {
padding:3px;
width:49%;
right:5px;
position:absolute;
}

.box:hover {
border:1px solid #AAAACC;
color:#000000;
}

.box {
color:#333333;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-radius:5px;
padding:8px;
margin-top:5px;
word-wrap:break-word;
text-align:justify;
cursor:default;
font-family:Cambria;
}

p {
margin:.5em;
text-indent:20px;
}
```

Also on a less important note I am wondering if I have improperly styled the bar at the top (in the jsfiddle), since I only wanted a shadow on the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `border-box`

```
body {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
}
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    padding-top:88px;
    width:100%;
}
.left { 
    width:50%;
    left:0;
    padding: 5px;
    position:absolute;
}
.right {
    right:0;
    width:50%; 
    padding: 5px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/sbz3k/2/

update, to make the shadow a bit more subtile, you can try something like this:

```
box-shadow:#000000 0px 1px 3px -1px;
```

Comment: That works nicely, but would you mind explaining what exactly the asterisk does?

Comment: of course, `*` is a wildcard or unversal selector, it applys to every element in your document but is also the one with the lowest priority, which makes it very easy to override it with more specific rules. You may also use it on parent items, to select all child, grand-child... nodes. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#universal-selector

Answer (score 3):

It may also be an idea to look into the [calc()](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) function

```
.left {
   padding:3px;
   width:calc(50% - 6px);
}
```

Comment: Omg, nice. Worked for me. http://jsfiddle.net/nn767x6L/ . Calc browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc